# How would I add every channel in a category onto a embed? Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

My plan for this would be to add every channel in a specific category onto an embed. Every month carlbot posts an embed with all of the current channels and each realm owner has to check in by reacting to their realm emojis. So this would be an example:

Realm Category :

#realm1-

#realm2-

#realm3-

---

Then after I say >checkin

The bot sends an embed with all of the channels.

Ex:
*React with your realm's emoji to check-in!*

realm1 - (emoji)

realm2 - (emoji)

realm3 - (emoji)

---

So far the only thing I'm having trouble with is collecting all of the channels in the category and creating a list or something with it. I'm fine with creating the embed and everything just with taking it and forming a list.

I took a stab and got this but I'm not sure if this is right or not.

```
category = client.get_channel(id_here)

for channel in category.voice_channels:
    #something here> await channel.???
```

Any tips would help greatly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
@client.command()
async def checkin(ctx):
    category = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.categories, id=your_id_here)
    embed = discord.Embed(title='Realms channels')
    
    for channel in category.channels: # or text_channels or voice_channels
        realm, emoji = channel.name.split('-')
        embed.add_field(name=realm, value=emoji)

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

It should look something like this *if I understood your question correctly*